# Linea en formato correo HTML

Tags: html, c#

buenas tardes. Al momento de hacer una solicitud se envia un correo a dicho cliente que hace una solicitud, y en el correo tengo varias tablas donde tengo datos del cliente que pone en la solicitud pero quiero separar con un

---

si en la dicha solicitud tengo 2 o más equipos que el cliente reporta en dicha solicitud.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las 2 lineas de arriba de la tabla son los hr que quiero poner entre cada equipo, num de serie y luego una linea separandolos

```
      EquiposNombre += "<tr> <th colspan = '3' scope = 'col' > Información de HW/SW </th> </tr>";
                    if (solicitud.ActivosReportados.Count != 0)
                    {

                        foreach (var e in solicitud.ActivosReportados)
                        {    
                             //EquiposNombre.Add(Utilidades.ActivoNombrePorActivoTipoIdActivoId(ar.ActivoId, ar.ActivoTipoId));
                             EquiposNombre += "<tr> <th scope='row'> Equipo: </th> <td>" + e.ActivoNombre + "</td> </tr>";
                             EquiposNombre += "<tr> <th scope='row'> Numero de Serie: </th> <td>" + Utilidades.ActivoNumSeriePorActivoTipoIdActivoId(e.ActivoId, e.ActivoTipoId) +"</td> </tr>";
                             if(solicitud.ActivosReportados.Count >= 2)
                             {
                                EquiposNombre += "<hr>";
                             }
                        }
                        
                    }
```

En el if es dentro del foreach es que si los activos reportados en la solicitud son 2 o más que se ponga una linea de bajo

Comment: Creo que la pregunta no es muy clara, qué es lo que no está funcionando en tu código actual?

Comment: Todo funciona bien pero no me funciona bien el if para agregar una nueva linea entre los tr de equipo y num de serie

Comment: Ya ve que las lineas en la imagen estan afuera de la tabla y no dentro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que las lineas dentro de una tabla no funcionan. Las tablas son estrictas en sus etiquetas, y no permiten eso que haces... aunque si lo hicieras así te deberia funcionar bien.
Cambia esto:

```
EquiposNombre += "<hr>";
```

por esto:

```
EquiposNombre += "<tr><td colspan='2'><hr></td></tr>";
```

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho.